# Usb-ethernet device

Tags: linux, networking

I have CP210x Composite Device. This device is USB-to-RS232 converter. When I plug it into Ubuntu-11.10, module named `cp210x` get inserted but I don't know why it did not create "usb0" network device ( which is the desired result ).

Does anyone knows, what is the process to make it work ?

> lsusb
>
> Bus 004 Device 005: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x Composite Device

Answer (score 3):

A USB-to-RS232 converter is going to give you a `/dev/ttyUSB0` or similar, and work as a serial port.

If you want to turn a serial port into a network interface, both sides need to be running PPP over it.  You'll want to look into `pppd` for Linux.  When it is configured correctly, you'll get a `ppp0` or similar that you can ping, route through, etc.  If the other side is Windows, read [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/entablish-a-ppp-connection-with-xp-as-server-and-linux-as-client-689776/).

They do make USB Ethernet adapters and those would work how you are describing.

Comment: Can't we use this USB-to-RS232 converter as a new network device ?  If I'm not wrong, then it should appear as usb0 in output of `ifconfig`

Comment: Searching reveals the CP210x is a "USB to UART" bridge chip.  No mention of Ethernet.  Unfortunately, the answer is no, and I'm very certain you are indeed wrong, my friend.  You might want to update your question with a picture of the cable just to be 100% certain (but right now I'm 99% certain).  Does it have an "RJ-45" jack on the non-USB side of it?  That type of jack is used for serial (i.e. NOT ethernet) cables and even phone lines, in addition to Ethernet cables.  This may have given you an incorrect impression of the converter's capabilities.